# Processing a large data-set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am new to modern JavaScript and trying to process a huge `JSON` data (or CSV) in JavaScript using `for-loops` and display the resultant chart using `Chart.js`. The process is time consuming and increases my wait time. Is there a technique to iterate and package my huge data efficiently in Java Script.

Thanks a lot, I'd really appreciate if you could help me out here.

Comment: you could delegate the work to a webworker (another thread)

Comment: Javascript runs on the client and should not be tasked with processing large amounts of data if you want to show the result quickly. Keep in mind there might be many users with a computer that is slower than yours. Process data on your server, over which you have full control, and only then send out the result in JSON to Chart.js.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried to process the data from node.js and send back the required array. Still I takes considerable amount of time for huge data. Is there any technique to minimize the processing time in node.js?

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks Jonas I will try to use webworkers. Quick question does web worker handle data size in Gigabits?

Comment: @naveen when you use a serverside approach, do a lot of caching. And no, gigabytes sounds wrong. On my internet connection it would take half a year to even load :)

Comment: @Naveen Downloading gigabytes of data to see a graph that could instead have been a 100kb jpeg, sounds like a lot of waste.